# Are SQL queries interpreted literally or does the SQL engine know how to optimize?

Tags: sql, algorithm

As a simple example, let's say we have the two tables

```
   Gibberish 
------------------
id  |  something
------------------
 1    "akldajansd"
 2    "asdnbbb"
 3    "laksjdktn"

      Translations
----------------------
id | gib_id | english
----------------------
 1    2       "Hello" 
 2    1       "I Love You"
```

and I run the query

```
SELECT G.something, T.english
FROM Gibberish AS G LEFT OUTER JOIN Translations as T 
ON G.id = T.gib_id
WHERE G.id > 1
```

Conceptually speaking, the part of the query

```
FROM Gibberish AS G LEFT OUTER JOIN Translations as T 
ON G.id = T.gib_id
```

is the table

```
G.id | G.something | T.id | T.gib_id | T.english
----------------------------------------------------------
 1   | "akldajansd"| NULL |   NULL   |  NULL      
 2   | "asdnbbb"   |  1   |   2      | "Hello"
 3   | "laksjdktn" | NULL |   NULL   |  NULL
```

which is then filtered by the clauses

```
SELECT G.something, T.english
```

and

```
WHERE G.id > 1
```

to eliminate some columns and rows.

But, if the SQL engine figures out the filtering first then the entire table

```
G.id | G.something | T.id | T.gib_id | T.english
----------------------------------------------------------
 1   | "akldajansd"| NULL |   NULL   |  NULL      
 2   | "asdnbbb"   |  1   |   2      | "Hello"
 3   | "laksjdktn" | NULL |   NULL   |  NULL
```

never needs to be built into memory. Right? And do SQL engines do this or when they parse the queries do they execute literally whatever clause they see?

Comment: SQL engines include an optimization step when they compile the query.  This is usually the first step when running a query, although plans can be cached or stored for later use.

Comment: The Azure SQL engine is the same one, or newer, that the box product has. It has an exceptional optimizer.

Comment: What you are talking about is called the query plan and you can actually see how it executes (For instance `EXPLAIN <SQL Statement>`  for postgres)
The way it runs depends on the nature of the columns (indexed or not) and also the way a table is partitioned in some databases. For instance, if you filter on an indexed column, the engine of your RDBMS won't have to scan all of the rows, just a part of it. If not, it will scan all the rows...
it's a whole science